# Error found when loading /home/[user]/.profile at boot

Tags: 18.04, login, .profile

Every time after I login, but before the desktop loads, a dialog box with the error:

```
Error found when loading /home/[user]/.profile
enp7s0: Unknown host
ifconfig: `--help' gives usage information.
```

I can just click OK and the dialog box disappears, and GNOME loads up afterwards.

However, the last 2 lines of the error message appear whenever I open a new terminal. I can still use the terminal, it just displays that error first.

I know that 'enp7s0' is my Ethernet profile. It also works correctly. So why would I get this error whenever I log in, and does it have any performance implications that I'm just not seeing?

Comment: Seems like you've made a change to your bashrc that's giving this error. Please post the output of `grep -nC2 ifconfig ~/.bashrc`. This will find any matches and give 2 context lines before and after, plus line numbers.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to serve up my IP to a live browser-sync server I was trying to run. Completely forgot about that it was so long ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `~/.profile` (or `~/.bashrc`) contains a `ifconfig` line that appears to not work. You can find that line and comment it out like this:

```
# ifconfig ...
```